# iphone - setUserInteractionEnabled problem

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a parent view contain a child custom view and many buttons. When I click on a button, it shows a child view and set [parentView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO]. Then I set 
[childView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]. But it's not working, the child view isnot able to be enabled. I don't why. Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: You can use `setUserInteractionEnabled` only on parent view. So all subview is this parent will work. If you set `setUserInteractionEnabled:NO` on parent view, then all subviews will not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 [parentView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

The snippet above disables user interaction for the `parentView` and all its subviews. So even if you follow it up with,

```
 [childView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

it won't work. You might want to rethink disabling user interaction on the parent view or do not add the `childView` as its subview.